# Android app displays correctly after device rotation but I haven't coded for it. How comes?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've been searching docmentation and forums, and from all I've read so far, I conclude that in order to support portrait **and** landscapce modes, I need to code two identically named layout XML files, one in res/layout, the other in res/layout-land. Each layout places the widgets corresponding to the mode.

But what if there is no corresponding layout in res/layout-land (or if the later doesn't even exist)?

From a simple app containing a single text view in a ConstriantLayout, I see that the layout correctly adapts to the device orientation when run on my physical phone.

However, when run on a virtual device (Pixel 4 XL API 28, if that matters), the view is **not** changed when I click on the *Rotate left* or *Rotate right* buttons.

[image]

But, after clicking on the rotate button, a *rotate* icon appears at the bottom right of the virtual device. Clicking on that rotates the view.

[image]

Basically, my questions are:

- Why is the layout correctly rotated on my physical device despite the fact that no landscape layout is present?
- Why does the virtual device **not** rotate the layout when clicking on the rotate buttons, but offers me a rotation by displaying a temporary rotate icon?

A pointer to some documentaiton where all this is described in detail would be nice. It sure must be documented; I just haven't been able to find it.

Comment: There's a quick settings tile for enabling auto-rotate. Does your physical device and emulator have those set differently?

Comment: @ianhanniballake: Do you mean the setting which locks/unlocks the screen orientation?

Comment: @ianhanniballake: Found it. Yep, it was set to "no auto-rotate" on the virtual device. Changing this resolved the problem. (I never change that setting on my phone, so I completely forgot about it.) Thanks for the quick help

Comment: Still the question remains: Why does rotation from portrait to landscape mode (and back) seem to properly work despite the fact that there is only one layout resource file? From all I read, I would have understood a seperate layout file for each orientation was a must-do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devices have a setting to enable or disable auto-rotation - on newer devices, when this is off, that rotate button appears which allows the user to choose to rotate (i.e., manually rotate).

As per the [providing alternative resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources), the most specific matching resource is used. So if you had a layout in `layout-land`, it will take precedence over that same resource in `layout`. (but wouldn't apply at all if you where in portrait mode as `-land` would disqualify that alternative resource).

That means that alternative resources are entirely optional - you'd only use them if your layout needs to be very different from one configuration to another. `ConstraintLayout`, for instance, uses relative positioning (i.e., position a view relative to the parent or to another view), which is often quite flexible to different orientations, screen sizes, etc. thus removing any need to need an entirely different landscape layout for a simple layout.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot.